# Run .ui File on Pycharm

Tags: python, user-interface, qt-designer

I am trying to test my first Python GUI on PyCharm using QT designer. I have everything I need and I searched the [QT designer help site](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins).

I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

This is my code:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(687, 221)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButton)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label)
        self.formLayout_2.setLayout(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.formLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Aceptar"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Facturacion"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Clientes"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Inventario"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Proveedores"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Log de Usuarios"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reportes"))
```

I'm trying to bring up the GUI with this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from Principal import Ui_MainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
```

Here is the error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arild/PycharmProjects/Reportes/Reportes.py", line 8, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(window)
  File "C:\Users\arild\PycharmProjects\Reportes\Principal.py", line 57, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
AttributeError: 'QDialog' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

Comment: What is actually happening? What do you expect to happen? [Please read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Im expecting a window to popup like the preview in QT designer.
the only thing that happens is the CDM windows pops up half a second then closes.

Comment: And what actually *is* happening? Any errors? Any anything? Are you sure it's executing? How are you sure? The response your system has is very important to diagnosing what is going on.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the debugger info, Just did the edit.

Comment: I cant seem to be able to bring the GUI interface with the code from the QT designer form.  the main error is this one: 
error MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with some corrections to the GUI syntax

Here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from Principal import Ui_MainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see I just changed the imports. It seems that I was importing the wrong `Widget`.

Here to compare:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, ***QDialog***
from Principal import Ui_MainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = ***QDialog()***
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
```

All of this is because the class object I am using is indeed a **Window**, not a Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error (`AttributeError: 'QDialog' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'`), I'm pretty sure you need this:

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
```

instead of this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
```

If you aren't inheriting the functions provided by `QMainWindow`, it won't be able to call them. Also, I think you're overriding the QT class `Ui_MainWindow`, which you don't want to do.

You may also need to do your setup on init:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):

    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    # or better
    # super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setupUi(self)
```